# Knockout With Binding Issue

Tags: knockout.js

I am having trouble with knockouts "With" binding. I can bind. I can bind a nested object no problem but not a nested model. am I doing it all wrong or is this out of the scope of the "with" binding.

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.anObject = {
        test: ko.observable("I'm and object bound by WITH.")   
    }

    var aFunction = function (){
        var self = this;
        self.test = ko.observable("I would like to be bound by WITH");   
    }

};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t3T5N/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.anObject = {
        test: ko.observable("I'm and object bound by WITH.")   
    }

    var ViewModel2 = function (){
        var self = this;
        self.test = ko.observable("I would like to be bound by WITH");   
    };

    self.aFunction = new ViewModel2();

};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: thanks! if you don't mind me extending the question a bit. how might this work with two way binding?

Comment: By default it's two way binding if you bind the property to an input element such as text.

Answer (score 2):

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.anObject = {
        test: ko.observable("I'm and object bound by WITH.")   
    }

    self.aFunction =ko.computed(function (){
        var self = this;
        self.test = ko.observable("I would like to be bound by WITH");
        return self.test;
    })
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ash_bars/qNdUK/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.anObject = {
        test: ko.observable("I'm and object bound by WITH.")   
    }

    self.aFunction = function (){
        var thisfunc = this;
        thisfunc.test = ko.observable("I would like to be bound by WITH");  
        return thisfunc;
    }

};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/K4EU5/1/

Comment: This is great. What is the difference between this and the below using ko.computed?

Comment: computed functions also observable object, if it depends from another observable object and you change it observable function changed his value.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274061/jquery-knockout-ko-computed-vs-classic-function

Comment: As Ashot mentioned, ko.computed automatically changes when the observables it depends on changes. I initially wanted to change your code to use computed, but thought I'd stay as true to your code as possible.